# Can't sudo in Debian 10

Tags: debian, sudo

I've got [Debian Buster/10](https://www.debian.org/releases/testing/) x86_64 in a VirtualBox VM for testing GCC 7. The Desktop is LXDE (don't select this in real life unless you are OK with SSH access; LXDE does not work in real life on Buster). I think the OS is really Debian 9 with Testing enabled.

I added myself to `sudo` and `adm` groups. There are no `sudoers`, `admin` or `wheel` groups:

```
# id jwalton
uid=1000(jwalton) gid=1000(jwalton) groups=1000(jwalton),4(adm),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),
29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),108(netdev),113(bluetooth),114(lpadmin),118(scanner)
```

I also uncommented the `sudo` group line in the sudoers file:

```
# cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I rebooted the machine. When I attempt to `sudo`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install emacs-nox
jwalton is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I went through the man page, but nothing jumped out at me as being bent. But its a large manual page, and I may have missed something obvious.

Why can't I `sudo`? What's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 16):

Did you uncomment the line or remove the leading `%`? Groups in `/etc/sudoers` begin with the percent sign. Your line should be:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

That allows anyone who is a member of the `sudo` group to use sudo.

Comment: I removed the `%` because adding myself to `sudo` group did not work. After the failure I assumed it was commented. Let me go back and re-add it.

Comment: OK, it looks like I needed to reboot. A logoff/logon did not enable it last time around. Thanks.

Comment: Odd, logging jwalton out and back in should have worked. Perhaps something in `/var/log/auth.log` will be helpful.

Comment: I logged in LXDE but could not logoff because its only a wall-papered screen (no icons, no taskbar, no start button, no interesting context menus like *Open Terminal*). I logged out via SSH after the change, but I'm guessing the derp'd session was still open due to the LXDE logon.